# How can we optimize Google's Autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Yesterday I was interviewed by XYZ Company, They gave me following real time problem to work on.

As we all know how google autocomplete works. It sends an AJAX call for each character you type in. So even when I haven't yet finished typing it sends all requests to server for each character I have pressed. (e.g I want to search `who is the biggest fool on the internet` then for each character it makes an AJAX call).

Question was "**How can we optimize this ?**"

I gave him solution to abort the previous ajax request if key is pressed again. But it seemed that interviewer was not convinced with this. So please suggest what could be the best solution for this ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Optimise in what sense? Interview questions are often deliberately open-ended, which isn't a very good fit for SO.

Answer (score 0):

Could probably keep track of last key press into search field, and so when some time passes (500ms or something) then send the search field's value.

Comment: nope...this is not solution. we can not hold user even for ms

Comment: From the moment you stop typing, waiting even for few seconds and then sending a single complete packet is too much? yes let's send 64 incomplete packets instead, sure. Also I don't see how aborting a previous ajax request is going to work, ajax packets are sent in an immediate form, only thing you can abort is receiving the response (and only quite frankly just by baling out of the response event callback).

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize by having the server send the delta from the last response. For example, suppose the user typed a few characters and recieved a list of the top 10 completions, which is displayed to the user. Now he types another character, so the server computes a new list of the top 10 completions. This list will probably have some completions in common with the previous list, and also a few new completions. So the idea is to only compute and send the new completions and along with their positions, so the client can update their list of top completions.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much you can do, simply because of the limitations you have to work with (browser, ajax, ...).

The only tricks I can think of would be:

1. you check each character. whitespace and other special characters do not trigger an ajax request, only any "real" character. That way "I am" only has 3 requests, instead of 4.
2. You add a "delay" (like 100ms) after the first character entered (or first two), that way you don't have a request for every single character, but only every 2 characters typed in. If someone types at an average speed that should save quite a few requests without feeling different.
3. instead of using ajax, you make a websocket connection. that way you can cancel the last request when a new character is entered. If you design your protocol carefully, you get the first few responses for the first character (which you already display), but ignore the rest, since the second response is already getting in.
4. you "preload" some data. This can be achievedby i.e. already loading the first responses for all letters (a-z) in the page itself, so when the user types the first char, there is actually no request, but still something to display.
5. If you work with technique 2, you can cheat a little and use client side parsing to filter the result from the last request for any terms "still" matching (i.e. the last request what "wh" -> and the user types in an "o", then you take the previous list of results, and keep all entries having "who" in it). That way you show something, even if the response is not here yet, and on the other hand, if there are enough results which mach the new term, you might decide not sending the request at all.